# How to install a reasonner and Dl query onto Webprotege?

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I'm looking for a tutorial explaining how to install a reasoner and dl query for webprotege (Protege is very good, but not for collaboration).
I need to have a step by step explanation.
There are two branches in the Github but they seems to be old and I want to use the newer version of webprotege.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately WebProtege is designed to be a very lightweight editor of ontologies therefore reasoning and querying is currently unavailable. It's definitely on the Protege team to do list [1] (additionally more contributors would be great if you want this feature added).

[1] http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-1265/owled2014_submission_15.pdf

Comment: Are the reasoning and querying available now?